# Scroll to bottom of component function only working when enter is pressed not when button is clicked

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a slack clone application and would like when the user adds a new message or when new messages come through it scroll to the bottom of the messages... When I reload the channel and or use enter to submit the message it works. however when I click the button nothing

I have tried several npm packages and moving the REF no luck

```
 componentDidUpdate(){
    {this.messagesEnd && this.scrollToBottom()}    

  }

  scrollToBottom = ()=> {

    this.messagesEnd.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})
   }
```

// add the send message on enter

```
handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        this.sendMessage()
    }

    const { message, typingRef, channel, user } = this.state;


    if(message){
        typingRef
           .child(channel.id)
           .child(user.uid)
           .set(user.displayName)
    }else{
        typingRef
        .child(channel.id)
        .child(user.uid)
        .remove()

    }

sendMessage = () => {
    const { getMessagesRef } = this.props;
    const { message, channel, user, typingRef } = this.state;


    if(message) {
        this.setState({loading: true});
        getMessagesRef()
            .child(channel.id)
            .push()
            .set(this.createMessage())
            .then(()=> {
                this.setState({loading: false, message: '', errors: [] });
                typingRef
                .child(channel.id)
                .child(user.uid)
                .remove()
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
                this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    errors: [...this.state.errors, err ]
                })
            })
    }else{
        this.setState({
            errors: [...this.state.errors, {message: "Add a message"}]
        })
    }
}

     <Fragment>
            <MessagesHeader 
            channelName = {this.displayChannelName(channel)}
            numUsers = {numUsers}
            handleSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange}
            searchLoading = {searchLoading}
            isPrivateChannel = {isPrivateChannel}
            handleStar = {this.handleStar}
            isChannelStarred = {isChannelStarred}

            />

                <Segment>

                        <Comment.Group className='messages'>


                            {this.displayMessagesSkeleton(messagesLoading)}
                            {searchTerm ? this.displayMessages(searchResults) : this.displayMessages(messages)  }

                            {this.displayTypingUsers(typingUsers)}
                            <div ref={node => this.messagesEnd = node}></div>                                               

                        </Comment.Group>


                </Segment>



            <MessageForm
            messagesRef ={messagesRef}
            currentChannel = {channel}
            currentUser = { user }
            isPrivateChannel = {isPrivateChannel}
            getMessagesRef = {this.getMessagesRef}
             />


        </Fragment>
```

Comment: Hi, Above shared code is not complete. Can you share code for sendMessage() methood also and how you are calling `<Comment.Group>` component inside `handleKeyDown` method?

Comment: I have added a bit more code

Answer (score 0):

Create a container component with fixed height e.g. 500px and inside that create another component with have all the messages (allMessages in below example)

```
<div>
  <div className={classes.messagesThread} ref={(container) => { this.container = container; }}>
    <div className={classes.container} ref={(allMessages) => { this.allMessages = allMessages; }}>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Create a method in your component to scroll the container like below to make the container to scroll to the bottom.

```
scroll = () => {
    if (this.container && this.allMessages) {
      this.container.scrollTop = this.allMessages.clientHeight;
    }
  }
```

Now this scroll method can be called on everytime user sends a new message or received a new message. Add below code to your componentDidUpdate lifecycle method.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps !== this.props.thread) {
      this.scroll();
    }
  }
```

As you can see in the above code, we have wrapped method invocation inside an if statement, that is for skipping additional re-renders. If you directly call the method then it will run each time prop and state update.
Note: My messages are in thread prop, you can change it to your prop name.

And also can be called on componentDidUUpdate lifecycle method to scroll to bottom by default on page load.

```
componentDidMount() {
    // by default scroll to bottom on load
    this.scroll();
  }
```